# How to make a chronometer in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I have few troubles to make a chronometer in QT, I need do it in a QLabel that displays "HH:MM:SS" that have elapsed since one button is pressed, do anyone have a easy way to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: using [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) and [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html)

Comment: button starts a timer, timer triggers every second, each second add a second to QTime, QTime::toString, QLabel::setText

Comment: @user3528438 - that won't be very accurate, each seconds will have a few milliseconds off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a `QElapsedTimer`. Then start a `QTimer`, and connect its timeout signal to a slot that gets `elapsedTimer.elapsed()`, converts the milliseconds since the timer was started to seconds, minutes and hours and update the label.

```
class Chronometer {
    QElapsedTimer t;
  public:
    void restart() { t.restart(); }
    QTime getTime() { return QTime(0,0).addMSecs(t.elapsed()); }
};

class ChronoUI : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    Chronometer c;
    QTimer t;
    QLabel * l;
    QPushButton * startB, * stopB;
  public:
    ChronoUI() {
      QVBoxLayout * ly = new QVBoxLayout;
      setLayout(ly);
      ly->addWidget(l = new QLabel(this));
      l->setText(QTime(0, 0).toString());
      ly->addWidget(startB = new QPushButton("start", this));
      ly->addWidget(stopB = new QPushButton("stop", this));
      connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTime()));
      connect(startB, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));
      connect(stopB, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &t, SLOT(stop()));
    }
  public slots:
    void updateTime() { l->setText(c.getTime().toString()); }
    void start() {
      l->setText(QTime(0, 0).toString());
      c.restart();
      t.start(1000);
    }
};
```

Or if you don't want to use an `QElapsedTimer`, you can use `QTime` in a similar way, although it has less resolution, `QTime` goes only as low as milliseconds, while `QElapsedTimer` can do nanoseconds on some platforms, both overkill if the lowest you want is seconds:

```
class ChronoUI : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QTime startTime;
    QTimer t;
    QLabel * l;
    QPushButton * startB, * stopB;
  public:
    ChronoUI() {
      QVBoxLayout * ly = new QVBoxLayout;
      setLayout(ly);
      ly->addWidget(l = new QLabel(this));
      l->setText(QTime(0, 0).toString());
      ly->addWidget(startB = new QPushButton("start", this));
      ly->addWidget(stopB = new QPushButton("stop", this));
      connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTime()));
      connect(startB, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));
      connect(stopB, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &t, SLOT(stop()));
    }
  public slots:
    void updateTime() { l->setText(QTime(0, 0).addMSecs(startTime.elapsed()).toString()); }
    void start() {
      l->setText(QTime(0, 0).toString());
      startTime.restart();
      t.start(1000);
    }
};
```